# Detecting/Listening to clicks, mouse movements and keydown events on the tinyMce editor on App.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, dom-events, tinymce

I have added an Idle timeout functionality to my React app which looks like this.

```
import React, { useEffect, useState }  from 'react';
import './App.css';
import Router from './utils/router';
import Store from './utils/store';
import SessionModal from "../src/components/modal/sessionModal";

const App = () => {

  const [isModalVisible, setModalVisible] = useState(false);

  useEffect(() => {
    let timeoutId;

    const handleActivity = () => {
      
      clearTimeout(timeoutId);
      timeoutId = setTimeout(() => setModalVisible(true), 5*1000); // 5 secs for testing
    };

    document.addEventListener('mousemove', handleActivity);
    document.addEventListener('keydown', handleActivity);
    document.addEventListener('scroll', handleActivity);
    document.addEventListener('click', handleActivity);
    document.addEventListener('KeyboardEvent', handleActivity);

    timeoutId = setTimeout(() => setModalVisible(true), 5*1000);
    
    return () => {
      clearTimeout(timeoutId);
      document.removeEventListener('mousemove', handleActivity);
      document.removeEventListener('keydown', handleActivity);
      document.removeEventListener('scroll', handleActivity);
      document.removeEventListener('click', handleActivity);
      document.removeEventListener('KeyboardEvent', handleActivity);
    };
  }, []);

  const sessionOutOK = () =>{
    setModalVisible(false);
    window.location.reload();
  }

  return (
  <Store>
          
      <Router>
      </Router>

      {isModalVisible && 
      <SessionModal
      props={{
        clickOK: sessionOutOK,
        clickCancel: sessionOutOK,
        title: "Planner",
        okTitle: "OK",
        noTitle: "",
        size: "sm",
        content: "Timed out! Please refresh the page",
      }}
    />

      }

  </Store>)

}

export default App;
```

This has worked well but the problem is using no keypresses, mouse movement or clicks are detected while I'm doing it on the text editor from TinyMCE which is in a completely different components file as one of its components.

For the sake of testing out atleast the Typing functionality, I have tried creating an event like this in `onEditorChange = {(value) =>{//CODE document.createEvent("KeyboardEvent"); }}` and tried listening to it on App.js using `document.addEventListener("KeyboardEvent", handleActivity);`

This has not worked. Alternatively I could store a variable in the sessionStorage or localStorage that updates when the editor is clicked and check it in App.js but I'm not sure if that's a good idea and how my API calls might be affected due to it. As for the mouse movement, I can overlook it as the actual timeout is over 6 mins.

```
                       <Editor
                        apiKey="ABC"
                        onInit={(evt, editor) => (editorRef.current = editor)}
                        value={letterBody}
                        init={{//CODE REMOVED}}
                        onEditorChange={(value) => {
                          setLetterBody(value);
                          setShowLetterBodyError(false);
                          setShowLengthError(false);
                          document.createEvent("KeyboardEvent");
                        }}
                        
                      />
```

Is there a way to listen to the keypresses on the TinyMCE editor from App.js?